# Nonlinear differential equation with imaginary number coefficient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $p$ be a polynomial. Does the differential equation,
$dy/dt=i \cdot p(y)$, with initial condition $y(0)=1$ always have a global solution (for all $t \in \mathbb R$)?

Comment: Does $p$ have complex coefficients or only real ones? You can split both $y$ and $p$ into their real and imaginary parts, to obtain a first-order system for $\mathrm{Re}(y)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(y)$. To this system you can apply Picard-Lindelöf.

Comment: I was thinking p has real coefficients.